# Is there a way to Export a layer/map list from AGOL

Tags: export, arcgis-online, csv, feature-service

We have just started using AGOL as an organization, and unfortunately it has gotten very disorganized fairly quickly. We were tasked with getting the layers/maps organized. It would really help if there was a way to export the the list of layers and maps that we have hosted on AGOL. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Who is doing the exporting (end users)?  Where do you want the export to take place?  What export data format are you interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Admin Tools for ArcGIS Online](https://marketplace.arcgis.com/listing.html?id=c34019b0623041608df4d06970a7a96a) is likely what you're looking for. It's a separate download (which I don't understand why it's not included), I regularly push lists out to see what layers reside under what groups and who owns what. It's proven to be a huge time saver and helps me keep things organized.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this. how did I not know this existed before!

Comment: Because it seems like it's not advertised at all  :)   Took a lot of digging for me to stumble upon it last year!